# dropdown button list is not shown over the screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I made a *dropdown* button that shows a list when I open a *navbar* page separately. But, a *dropdown* is not show over the screen when I include this *navbar* page with another page

[image: screenshot 1]
That's the output when I open this header page

[image: screenshot 2]
when I merge this navbar page with other page dropdown list are not show

```css
.brandlogo {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.menulines {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.adminbtn {
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  line-height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header style="position: sticky;top: 0;width: 100%">
  <div class="topheadadmin">

    <div class="brandlogo">
      <span class="menulines" onclick="opennav()">&#9776;</span>
      <a href="adminpanel.php" style="list-style: none;text-decoration: none;color: white">Admin Panel</a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle adminbtn" aria-expanded="true" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Admin</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">

        <a href="" class="dropdown-item"><span class="fa fa-lock"></span>&nbsp;profile</a>
        <a href="" class="dropdown-item"><span class="fa fa-lock"></span>&nbsp;Change Password</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>

        <a href="" class="dropdown-item"><span class="fa fa-power-off"></span>&nbsp;Logout</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Why do you have CSS in the page below `<header>`?

Comment: @Marc Bad etiquette, but still works.

Comment: @Marc that's my first question on stack overflow that's why I mistakenly paste the html and css code on same page

Comment: @Marc that's my first question on stack flow i paste html and css code on same page but in real both are in different files means <header> section are in 'navbar.php' and css are in 'style.css'